# "By" to mean "in result of" or "After" - by + gerund

Tags: gerunds

I have made the following sentence

> By selecting (or clicking on) an element, a dialogue opens in which one can ...

I used "By" just on my intuition, but I am not sure if it means as I expect. It should mean "after (or as a result of ) selecting or clicking on an element, a dialogue opens ....

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence is correct. Your definition isn't perfect.

By does not mean after.

In this context it's similar to "how something is accomplished." 
So using by to mean as a result of is pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

By opening the windows you get fresh air.

"by+gerund" gives the act necessary to get a certain effect. What does your dictionary say about by + gerund?  You also can google for by + gerund to get explanations and exercises.

http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/gerund3.html

Answer (score -1):

> As he select an element, a dialogue box will open up in which he can select
>   various distinguish properties of the element

Comment: Your sentence seems to be awkwardly written. The dialogue box doesn't open at the same time the element is selected, but after and there are other issues.

Comment: let me know other issues.. it will help me in learning